# Why does intellij open two terminals when I right click a folder in project explorer and choose "Open in Terminal"?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I close all my current terminal windows then right click a folder in my project and choose "Open in Terminal" I see this:

[image]

It drops me into "Local(2)" but also opens "Local". Why does it do this? Can I have intellij just open one terminal when I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a cosmetic issue. Opening Terminal tool window automatically starts the terminal in the current project root.

When you invoke the Open in Terminal for a folder, the following happens:

1. Terminal tool window opens automatically starting the shell in the project root
2. An action to open a terminal in the selected folder is called which leads to the second tab open

Bug report [is welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA).

Comment: well i didnt ask how to fix it so I guess this is the right answer haha. Is there any workaround until its fixed?